# Routing with UI Router in Angular JS App gives a blank screen when I test on Https Server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

Here is my app.js code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'firebase']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
    .state('site', {
        url: '/site',
        templateUrl: 'partials/site.html'
    })
    .state('site.home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'
    })
    .state('site.about', {
        url: '/about',
        templateUrl: 'partials/about.html'
    })
    .state('site.projects', {
        url: '/projects',
        templateUrl: 'partials/projects.html'
    })
    .state('site.blog', {
        url: '/blog',
        templateUrl: 'partials/blog.html'
        controller: 'BlogCtrl'
    })
    .state('site.login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'partials/login.html'
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    })
    .state('site.newpost', {
        url: '/newpost',
        templateUrl: 'partials/newpost.html',
        controller: 'NewPostCtrl'
    })
    .state('site', {
        url: '/contact',
        templateUrl: 'partials/contact.html'
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwsie('/site/home');
})
```

This is the index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset= "utf-8">

        <title>Portfolio</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <!-- Angular -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.11/angular.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Angular UI Router -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.13/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

        <!-- Angular Animate -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.13/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Firebase -->
        <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.0/firebase.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.9.1/angularfire.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Controllers -->
        <script src="js/controllers/BlogCtrl.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/LoginCtrl.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/NewPostCtrl.js"></script>

        <!-- App -->
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>

        <!-- Styling -->
        <link rel="stylsheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
        <link rel="stylsheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css">

    </head>

    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div ui-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I try and test the code locally using "http-server -a localhost -p 3000", it just shows a blank page that is my index.html page. I think it is some routing error but I can't see the bug, any ideas for fixes?

It also states that app is not defined in this js file:

```
'use strict'

app.controller('BlogCtrl', function($scope, $firebase, $firebaseArray, FireRef, $state){
    var data = $firebaseArray(FireRef);
    $scope.posts = data;

    $scope.$watch('posts', function(newValue, oldValue){
        $scope.posts = $sce.trustAsHtml(data);
    })

    $scope.login = function() {
        $state.go('site.login');
    }

    $scope.newPost = function(){
        $state.go('site.newPost');
    }
});
```

Comment: code seem ok..is there any error in console? make sure template path's are correct.

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.11/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%…dflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.3.11%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A350)

Comment: It says a module failed to load

Comment: you need to check..some js file doesn't get loaded..

Comment: i edited the question to include one more possible source of error, the console does state that line three in that js file, app is not defined. How do I fix that?

Comment: use angular.module('myApp') instead of defining an app variable.

Comment: thanks, that got rid of the module error. Now how do I refer to app such as in app.config now that I dont have a variable name though?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you have 'use strict,' so it doesn't know what 'app' is.  You need to add the line `var app = angular.module('myApp');` before you can use `app.controller` syntax.